# c++ what type should I use in this dll script?

Tags: c++, autohotkey

Here is the part of my dll which works fine but I want to improve it:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void RightClick()
    {   
        hWindow = FindWindow(NULL, "My Window title");
        [...]
    }
```

What I'd like to have is something like this:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void RightClick(**TYPE** variable)
    {   
        hWindow = FindWindow(NULL, **TYPE** variable);
        [...]
    }
```

Where variable is string, for example "Notepad - Untitled" which I can call in my autohotkey script, examplery:

```
f3::    
DllCall("Project4.dll\RightClick", **TYPE**, "Notepad - Untitled")
return
```

Comment: `const char*` .

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation of [FindWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you should use `LPCTSTR`. It's a `const TCHAR` string. `TCHAR` is a `wchar_t` if you build your dll for Unicode charset or `char` otherwise.